# How can I figure out where the toilet overflow pipe goes?

Tags: plumbing, water, leak, toilet

In the toilet tank I know that the overflow pipe is there for when the toilet tank is full. However my toilets overflow pipe in the tank doesn't go back into the toilet it goes to a pipe which runs along the waste pipe but what is that pipe attached to? where does it go. We have a major leak that no one can find and I am worried that pipe is the issue when it goes into the wall that it then isn't attached to anything.
We know none of out live pipes are the issue and not our drains and waste pipe as water is clean.

Comment: Are you in the UK, US, elsewhere? In the UK, an overflow pipe from a toilet cistern usually goes straight through the wall, and drips down the outside of the house.

Comment: Hi Andy T the wall is now and interior wall as the previous owners built a garage. It appears when they did this they didn't attached it anywhere or direct it to the new outside wall!

Comment: The previous owners (or their builders) were clearly idiots! When I wanted to get rid of a toilet overflow pipe, I changed the cistern fittings to a modern type to overflow into the bowl.

Comment: I know! the issue is that it the insurance say it is negligence but clearly not on our part! surely we could not know the issue behind a wall on a garage that was build 20 years ago! If the toilet had not been slightly going down the overflow we would have never know it was a problem. It has made so much damage. We have had to take up a floor and so many walls have water damage. Oh well at least after a year we now know what the leak is. I should hire myself out as a leak detector.:)

Answer (score 1):

The overflow pipe is for when the tank is full AND the normal fill-control system for the tank fails. If there is water entering the overflow pipe either due to a failed fill control setup or due to a leak in the connections at the bottom of the tank then that is a problem that should be fixed.

I would suggest adding some food coloring or similar dye into the tank. This should allow you to quickly determine if the water is coming from the tank or not.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answers! Much appreciated. My overflow doesn't flow into the bowl like most modern toilets but goes through a pipe into the wall. We had no clue where it went and had to take wall down and found it wasn't attached to anything just water coming out into the wall as the water ballcock wasn't shutting off the water going into the tank. Food colouring helped us identify it. We have spend £1000 having water pipes, drains, roofing and flooring taken up for me to solve it myself yesterday. 5 people have looked at the toilet none of whom identified that toilet as the culprit

Comment: Sadly dealing with bodges left behind by previous owners seems to be an unavoidable part of home ownership.